# how to redirect to another database and its table when selecting a specific row from a table in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

kind people! I have a question about the database.
There are several databases, in each of them there are several tables.
And there is a main database, in which there is only one table containing information
about these databases and tables.
The question is: how to make so that when you select specific information from the table in the main database it automatically forwards you to another database outputting its tables? Sorry for asking this kind of bit tricky question, i have been googling all day and still cannot find solution. i have tried by my own.. but no results.

Comment: any ideas of how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

For now I made something like this, but I am not sure whether I am right

```
DECLARE @a nvarchar(100)
SET @a= (select * from MasterDB.dbo.Clients_Master_Table);

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'select * from '+ @a +' where Client_Name= somedatabse name'
```